# Print in android

Tags: android

How to print from android tablet without using any apps provided by android play Store. 
I would like to print from webview just by clicking one button in my activity. So for example, if i click print button in my activity , it should just print the current content of webview without asking / taking me to settings options.

Comment: There is no printing support built into Android.

Answer (score 2):

Android has no built-in printing support, so unless you mean printing to an `OutputStream`, this is not possible. Which means you still need some `Google Play` apps, like [PrinterShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare) or [Cloud Print](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.pauloslf.cloudprint%26hl%3Den&ei=pFP9UMizLIaJ0AXz2YGQDQ&usg=AFQjCNH2XZ1M-FS1TB91zLZaGSyn-jkQkQ).

*Short answer: **Not possible***

Comment: how abt if i dont want user to chose anything but directly print content of webview when he clicks a button?

Comment: @user1932345 As the answer says, Android does not support this out-of-the-box, so you'll *need* an app.

Answer (score 2):

If I can add something.. the new Android ships with a built-in printing framework, as stated on the Android 4.4 page.

> Android now includes a complete framework that allows users to print any document using a printer connected over Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or other services. The system handles the transaction between an app that wants to print a document and the services that deliver print jobs to a printer. The android.print framework provides all the APIs necessary to specify a print document and deliver it to the system for printing. Which APIs you actually need for a given print job depends on your content.

The bad news is that **it's only for API 19 and later**. So if you're targeting >= Android 4.4 versions (1.8% to date, according to [Androiddistribution.com](http://androiddistribution.com/)) just stick with the API.

Answer (score -2):

Android direct USB printing using OTG cable is available through a small library.
see link http://myhowtohelp.blogspot.in/2014/01/library-to-print-from-android-device-usb.html